# Create instance of class and call method from string

Tags: c#, reflection

```
String ClassName =  "MyClass"
String MethodName = "MyMethod"
```

I would like to achieve:

```
var class = new MyClass; 
MyClass.MyMethod();
```

I saw some e.g. with reflection  , but they only show , either having a method name as string or class name as string, any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? I'm asking because most reflection questions are [XY-Problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in my experience.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where you get stucked.

Comment: If you have seen an example that uses reflection to create a class and another to call a method then just combine them and if it doesn't work post the code and results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// Find a type you want to instantiate: you need to know the assembly it's in for it, we assume that all is is one assembly for simplicity
// You should be careful, because ClassName should be full name, which means it should include all the namespaces, like "ConsoleApplication.MyClass"
// Not just "MyClass"
Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(ClassName);
// Create an instance of the type
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
// Get MethodInfo, reflection class that is responsible for storing all relevant information about one method that type defines
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(MethodName);
// I've assumed that method we want to call is declared like this
// public void MyMethod() { ... }
// So we pass an instance to call it on and empty parameter list
method.Invoke(instance, new object[0]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Something similar, probably with more checks:

```
string typeName = "System.Console"; // remember the namespace
string methodName = "Clear";

Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);

if (type != null)
{
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName);

    if (method != null) 
    {
        method.Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

Note that if you have parameters to pass then you'll need to change the `method.Invoke` to

```
method.Invoke(null, new object[] { par1, par2 });
```