# How to call component with same as string "component name" in html using angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, reflection, angular-components

I'm trying to call components with the string keys in angular 7. Because my service gives me keys which component filters about to show on page per user. Can i make this filter especially in html?

```
<pg-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index">
  <ng-template #TabHeading>
    {{tab.headerText}}
  <a (click)="removeTab(index)" style="padding: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" style="color:orangered;"></i></a>
  </ng-template>
  <div class="row column-seperation" *ngIf="tab.componentName === 'grid-sample'">
    <app-grid-sample></app-grid-sample>
  </div>

  <div class="row column-seperation" *ngIf="tab.componentName === 'pdf-export-sample'">
    <app-pdf-export-sample></app-pdf-export-sample>
  </div>
  <div class="row column-seperation" *ngIf="tab.componentName === 'notify-sample'">
    <app-notify-sample></app-notify-sample>
  </div>
  <div class="row column-seperation" *ngIf="tab.componentName === 'loader-sample'">
    <app-loader-sample></app-loader-sample>
  </div>
  <div class="row column-seperation" *ngIf="tab.componentName === 'tt-form-elements'">
    <app-tt-form-elements></app-tt-form-elements>
  </div>
  <div class="row column-seperation" *ngIf="tab.componentName === 'tt-layouts'">
    <app-tt-layouts></app-tt-layouts>
  </div>
</pg-tab>
```

I searched about innerHtml attribute but it's not working for angular components like in that example.

html

```
<div [innerHTML]="pageDetail"></div>
```

typescript

```
private _pageDetail: string = '<app-tab-page1 [tab]="tab" [tabsLength]="tabs.length" [tabs]="tabs"></app-tab-page1><button>Naber</button>';

public get pageDetail(): SafeHtml {
  return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this._pageDetail);
}
```

You can guess it's not looking good right now. If it's possible, I want to turn shorter and clean that "*ngIf" attributes in html.

Do you have any ideas about it?

Something like this

```
<div class="row column-seperation" tab.componentName>
  <app-tab.componentName></app-tab.componentName>
</div>
```

Note: Sorry for my grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dynamic component with name like this:

Tab item is a directive:

```
@ViewChildren('tabItem', {read: ViewContainerRef} ) tabItem:  QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
```

Here create dynamic component:

```
    const factories = Array.from(this.componentFactoryResolver['_factories'].keys());
    const factoryClass = <Type<any>>factories.find((x: any) => x.name === dynamicComponentName);
    if (factoryClass !== undefined) {
      const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(factoryClass);
      const ref = this.tabItem.viewContainerRef;
      ref.createComponent(factory);
    }
```

Also you can look the angular docs: [dynamic component](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Using `ngSwitch` will not help much to reduce the html code.
2. Using `ngComponentOutlet` the component to display can be provided from parent component code instead of template.

Example for #2:

template:

```
<div>
... some other code
 <ng-template matTabContent>
     <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="screen.component; injector: screen.injector">
     </ng-container>
 </ng-template>
</div>
```

Parent component code:

```
export class TabsContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  // make sure these component are also added to entryComponents
  private components = [
    GridSampleComponent,
    NotifySampleComponent,
    LoaderSampleComponent,
    TTLayoutComponent,
    ...
  ];

  screen: any; // reference to be used by the ngComponentOutlet in the template

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    const tabs = await this.someApiService.getComponentFilters().toPromise();
    const injector = Injector.create({
        providers: [any providers you want to pass to the component],
        parent: this.injector
    })

    switch (tabs.componentName) {
        case 'grid-sample':
            screen = { component: GridSampleComponent, injector };
            break;
        case 'notify-sample':
            screen = { component: NotifySampleComponent, injector };
            break;
        case 'loader-sample':
            screen = { component: LoaderSampleComponent, injector };
            break;
        case 'tt-layout':
            screen = { component: TTLayoutComponent, injector };
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can we call that components with string? For example: screen = { component: "GridSampleComponent", injector };

Comment: You need to put your class in code anyways. I want to make it dynamically in anywhere. Like reflection in c#. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29034215/2351529

Comment: For the dependency injection to work, Angular needs to know the component at compile time. Hence the requirement to at-least add them in `entryComponents` array. Alternately, have a look at `componentFactoryResolver` api if you want to dynamically load a component.

Comment: Even for reflection, the class definition has to be part of the final/release bundle. In Angular `entryComponents` is an array to register component which are not directly or immediately used in the app, but instantiated at a later point in time.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use ngSwitch which will make it shorter, but dynamic component name is from what i know not possible,

```
<div class="row column-seperation" *ngSwitch="tab.componentName">
    <app-grid-sample *ngSwitchCase="'grid-sample'"></app-grid-sample>
    <app-pdf-export-sample *ngSwitchCase="'pdf-export-sample''"></app-pdf-export-sample>
     //etc ...
  </div>
```

Comment: Actually that etc is a problem for me. it can be so long and i want to forget that place when i add new components.